# Camel writing to OracleAQ issues

Tags: java, oracle, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Trying to come up with a Camel flow that would write messages to an OracleAQ topic, but i keep getting this error in Camel logs..

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; 

nested exception is oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-204: An error occurred in the AQ JNI layer; nested exception is oracle.jms.AQjmsException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I do have aqapi13.jar in my applications claspath. The Oracle version is 11i and the camel version is 2.12.0

Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

Comment: This seems not to be Camel problem but a problem with the OracleAQ configuration: missing DB table or missing permissions to read the DB tables.

Comment: Agree, this does not look like a Camel issue.